# How to properly split my train and inference decoders?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I created a Dataset API pipeline and a seq2seq encoder-decoder model using contrib seq2seq API.

I'm creating two different decoders (that share the same Weights):

- one to train my model, using teacher forcing (TrainHelper)
- one to test my model, using decoder outputs as inputs (GreedyEmbeddingHelper)

However, I can't use my model because I'm calling the decoder function two times:

1. Giving training dataset as argument to build my model
2. Giving testing dataset as argument to build my model

Calling the function two times, I'm duplicating some variables.

Here is my decoder function that creates both training and inference decoders:

```py
def decoder(target, hidden_state, encoder_outputs):
  with tf.name_scope("decoder"):
    # ... embedding the targets
    decoder_inputs = embeddings(target) 

    decoder_gru_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.GRUCell(dec_units, name="gru_cell")

    # Here I create the training decoder part
    with tf.variable_scope("decoder"):

      training_helper = tf.contrib.seq2seq.TrainingHelper(decoder_inputs, max_length)
      training_decoder = tf.contrib.seq2seq.BasicDecoder(decoder_gru_cell, training_helper, hidden_state)
      training_decoder_outputs, _, _ = tf.contrib.seq2seq.dynamic_decode(training_decoder, max_length)


    # And here I create the inference decoder part
    with tf.variable_scope("decoder", reuse=True):

      inference_helper = tf.contrib.seq2seq.GreedyEmbeddingHelper(...)
      inference_decoder = tf.contrib.seq2seq.BasicDecoder(decoder_gru_cell, inference_helper, hidden_state)
      inference_decoder_outputs, _, _ = tf.contrib.seq2seq.dynamic_decode(inference_decoder, max_length)


  return training_decoder_outputs, inference_decoder_outputs
```

And here I create my model:

```py
def seq2_seq2_model(values, labels):
  encoder_outputs, hidden_state = encoder(values)
  training_decoder, inference_decoder = decoder(labels, hidden_state, encoder_outputs)

  return training_decoder, inference_decoder
```

Here are my dataset,that I split in train part and testing part (size n_test):

```py
values_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(values)
labels_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(labels)

X_Y_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.zip((features_dataset, caption_dataset))

X_Y_test = X_Y_dataset.take(n_test).batch(n_test)
X_Y_train = X_Y_dataset.skip(n_test).batch(batch_size)

test_iterator = X_Y_test.make_initializable_iterator()
x_y_test_next = test_iterator.get_next()

train_iterator = X_Y_train.make_initializable_iterator()
x_y_train_next = train_iterator.get_next()
```

Finally, I build my model by calling seq2_seq2_model:

```py
training_decoder_outputs, _ = seq2_seq2_model(*x_y_train_next)
_, inference_decoder_outputs = seq2_seq2_model(*x_y_test_next)
```

Here comes the error, because I'm creating two times the variable decoder_gru_cell.

```py
ValueError: Variable decoder/decoder/attention_wrapper/gru_cell/gates/kernel already exists, disallowed.
```

I can create a global variable for the duplicated variables, but it seems to be a dirty way to corect the problem. In addition, the code I'm showing is a simplified version of mine: I would have to create several global variables...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found. 
The key is to use a reinitializable iterator, in order to switch dataset as input source.

```py
data_iterator = tf.data.Iterator.from_structure(X_Y_test.output_types,
                                               X_Y_train.output_shapes)

train_init_op = data_iterator.make_initializer(X_Y_train)
test_init_op = data_iterator.make_initializer(X_Y_test)

values, labels = data_iterator.get_next()
```

Then we can create the decoder in one step:

```py
training_decoder_outputs, inference_decoder_outputs = seq2_seq2_model(values, labels)
```

Finally we use the train_init_op and test_init_op to specify if we want to use the train dataset or the test_dataset:

```py
with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(init)

  sess.run(train_init_op)
  # Perform training...

  sess.run(test_init_op)
  # Perform inference...
```